# how to (f)sync a directory under linux in c

Tags: c, filesystems, fsync

I've some c application under linux. I'm renaming some files with `rename(...)`
How can I ensure that the renaming is written persistent to the underlaying disk?

With a file I can do something like:

```
FILE * f = fopen("foo","w");
...
fflush(f);
fsync(fileno(f));
fclose(f);
```

How can I `fsync` (or similar) a directory after a `rename()` in c?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do what you want:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int fd = open('/path/to/dir', O_RDONLY);
fsync(fd);
```

Don't forget to close the `fd` file descriptor when no longer needed of course.

Contrary to some misconceptions, the atomicity of `rename()` does not guarantee the file will be persisted to disk. The atomicity guarantee only ensures that the metadata in the file system buffers is in a consistent state but not that it has been persisted to disk.

Answer (score 1):

`rename()` is atomic (on linux), so I don't think you need to worry about that

> Atomicity is typically guaranteed in operations involving filename handling ; for example, for rename, “specification requires that the action of the function be atomic” – that is, when renaming a file from the old name to the new one, at no circumstances should you ever see the two files at the same time.
>
> a power outage in the middle of a rename() operation shall not leave the filesystem in a “weird” state, with the filename being unreachable because its metadata has been corrupted. (ie. either the operation is lost, or the operation is committed.)

[Source](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2013/11/15/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-fsync/)

So, I think you should only be worried about error value.

---

If you really want to be safe, [`fsync()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) also flush metadata (on linux), so you could `fsync` the directory and the file you want to be sure there are present on the disk.

Comment: It is atomic on POSIX systems.  The C standard says nothing about it.

Comment: How to get the "File Handle" of the directory?

Comment: @powerpete I think you can open a directory like any other file (only read mode)

Comment: opendir(..)? open(...)? fopen(...)?

Comment: @powerpete do you often open file with `opendir()` ? `open()` or `fopen()` would do the job, I don't think `opendir()` would be accept by `fsync()` as it's a little special.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), at the return of the function, `rename` has been done  effectively (return 0) or an error occured (return -1) and `errno` is set to check what's wrong.

If you want the system to apply the potential pending modifications only on this file after `rename` you can do :

```
int fd = open(new_name, O_RDONLY);
syncfs(fd);
```